# How can I improve the responsiveness of this FileReader?

Tags: javascript, memory, filereader

How you I go about improving the responsiveness of this file reader I made?

I created a simple animation to see how it effects the UI and it really blocks the UI quite substantially.

I even tried using `File.slice` to read the file in chunks but it only seems to garner a minor performance increase at the expense of taking much longer to load the file.

There is a fiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/8A3tP/2/

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get a bit of a better result by loading each of them sequentially using a recursive function in place of the for loop: http://jsfiddle.net/8A3tP/5/

Comment: Have you tried to `setTimeout` those recursive calls?

Comment: There's a setTimeout on the call to readBlob(). I've added an options array so I can easily tweak it. Check the updated fiddle for an improvement.